# ContinueWith and TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext on blazor wasm

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm porting old WinForms code to blazor that uses Task.ContinueWith() passing  TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() as parameter to run the continuation on the UI thread.

It works fine on blazor server, but throws an exception on blazor wasm:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler.
```

SynchronizationContext.Current is null in blazor wasm, probably because is not needed as the browser is single threaded, but why not to set a dummy SynchronizationContext for compatibility? Can I do it myself?

Comment: Why not just remove that code?

Comment: As above, why not simplify the code using modern standard async and awaits.  Without more context we can only make general suggestions.